# Identifying problematic csv file in rbind process - error message

Tags: r

Every few months I receive about 200 csv files that I  combine (rbind) into a single data set. I found online the following script that does the job nicely.

```
setwd("directory that contains my csv files")
filenames <- list.files()
dt <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE))
```

However, the script will not work unless the files have identical number of columns and column names. Lately, about 10% of the files I receive have column names misspelled or have the wrong number of columns.

Is there a way of making a list of the files that do not work so I can notify their sender to fix them.

You can replicate the example by assuming that I have the following 4 files.

file1.csv 
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6

file2.csv 
A B C
4 5 6
3 2 1

file3.csv
A B D
7 8 9
6 5 4

file4.csv
A B C D E 
7 8 9 4 5
6 5 4 2 3

I hope to be able to generate a list that simply shows

file3.csv 
 flle4.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your data.frames before `rbind`:

```
 nn <- c('A','B','C')
 ll <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE)
 do.call(rbind,lapply(ll,function(x){ 
        if(names(x) '%in%' nn)
           x[,nn]               ## this will select the columns 
                                ##   in the desired order
        else
           x <- setnames(x,nn)  ## otherwise rename ( the D case)
        x
 }))
```

Comment: Your input made me realize that I needed to further clarify my problem. Your suggestion assumes that all submitted files are having the correct setup. I have updated my question to add a scenario showing the users may alter the sequence of fields. Bottom line, I need to identify the errant file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TCS you should just take care of this particular case. but the idea is the same. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filenames   <-  c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv")
sapply(filenames, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE, nrows = 1)
```

giving this:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
V1 "A"  "A"  "A" 
V2 "B"  "B"  "B" 
V3 "C"  "C"  "D"
```

if there is unequal number of columns, then it will return a list

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I can picture a solution, but I don't know how to execute it. If we assume that the first csv has the correct fields, then I would like to create new data set that has two variables. The first one simply provides the list of the csv filenames. The second one is a binary variable (T/F) that compares the names of the first file versus the names  of each one of the remaining files, and return T or F. This way I can quickly focus on just the files for which the result of the comparison is F. Thank you for your help.